# Find powers of 3 mod 17

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, congruences, primitive-roots

Show that powers of $3\ (\text{mod}\ 17)$ are $3,9,10,13,15,11,16,14,8,7,4,12,2,6,1$.
What is meaning of power of something, how do I proceed this question? Just provide me hint to get start in this problem.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1465046/to-show-congruence

Comment: @labbhttacharjee   how does it relate to this question ?

Comment: we calculated $3^4,3^8\pmod{17}$ there, right?

Comment: The $n$-th power of $a$ is $a^n$ as usual.

Comment: got it....., thanks @lab bhattatacharjee

Comment: The long way: Calculate the powers of $3$ modulo $17$, one after the other. We get $3$, $9$, $27$ which mod $17$ simplifies to $10$. Now multiply by $3$, reduce mod $17$. We get $30$, which is $13$, Multiply by $3$, reduce modulo $17$. We get $5$. Multiply by $3$, reduce (nothing happens). We get $15$. Continue. But there is a shortcut. If we find that $3^8$ is not congruent to $1$, we know all numbers from $1$ to $16$ will occur as residues of powers of $3$. And $3^8$ can be found in three squarings modulo $17$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us try a very naive approach. I should add that this is precisely the method suggested in  [André Nicolas's comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1465079/find-powers-of-3-mod-17#comment2983490_1465079).

You start by $3^0=1$ and multiply both sides by $3$ repeatedly
$$3^0 \equiv 1 \pmod{17}\\
3^1 \equiv 3 \pmod{17}\\
3^2 \equiv 9 \pmod{17}$$
The next result would be $3^3 \equiv 27 \pmod{17}$. But $27\equiv10\pmod{17}$. 
$$
3^3 \equiv 10 \pmod{17}\\
3^4 \equiv 13 \pmod{17}\\
$$
We can also use $3^4 \equiv -4 \pmod{17}$ if it makes computation easier. In this case we either multiply $-4$ or $13$ by $3$. But in both case we get $-12 \equiv 5 \pmod{17}$ and $39 \equiv 5 \pmod{17}$.
$$
3^5 \equiv 5 \pmod{17}\\
3^6 \equiv 15 \pmod{17}\\
3^7 \equiv 11 \pmod{17}\\
3^8 \equiv 16 \pmod{17}\\$$
We continue this way until we get $1$ and the sequence starts to repeat. Or we could notice that $3^8\equiv-1\pmod{17}$, so from this point on we can repeat the same numbers we already have but with the minus sign.